# When writing iphone applications with actionscript, is it possible to read from devices such as the gps?

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, hardware, gps

As announced, [it is now possible to develop Iphone applications with Actionscript](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashcs5/appsfor_iphone/).

My question is: is it possible to control iphone devices such as the GPS receiver and/or camera using actionscript? Is there somekind of "AS3 for the Iphone"-framework?

I know my question is short, but this is all I need to know for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Applications_for_iPhone#Which_native_iPhone_APIs_and_functionality_are_supported_when_using_Flash_tooling.3F